# Как убрать конфликт между якорем и табами?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая ситуация, имею на сайте и табы и якорь. И при нужде привязывать якорь к кое-каким функциям пришлось ставить скрипт.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function () {
var target = $(this).attr('href');
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 250 }, 800);

  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.hash=target;
  },100);


return false;
});
```

Но скрипт зацепает все остальное что связано с href, возможно ли как то фильтровать для каких #хешей( так как их много) именно якорь должен срабатывать.

Пробывал прописывать ##tag - в этом случаее скрипт не зацыпает табы.

Но для хешей он работать правильно отказывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уточните селектор - добавьте дополнительные критерии для выборки. Например, что бы якоря были внутри определённого блока.

Ещё можете исключить ваши табы из выборки

```
$('a[href^="#"]').not('<your_tab_selector>')
```

Например, если у вас такая разметка

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>

...

<a href="#my-anchor">My Custom anchor</a>
```

Вы можете сделать такой селектор

```
$('a[href^="#"]').not('.nav-link')
```

Или такой

```
$('a[href^=#]:not(.nav-link)')
```

Comment: Вот первое то что вы сказали супер, и как это сделать?.
Якорь считается ссылкой или то место куда установлен?

Comment: Получается что табы разбросаны по всему сайту,

Comment: Ну тут трудно говорить что-то не зная ваш код. У ваших табов или якорей есть какой-то общий критерий. Или вы можете его добавить: атрибут или класс.

Comment: обычные табы бутстраповские, просто суть в том что при нажатии на таб запускается этот скрипт, а он предназначен только для якорей, вот тут и проблема. потому что что табы запускаются по хешу что якоря, это основа их работы, а я хочу что бы только якоря зацепало, тоесть скрипт выдает для все хешей

Comment: если bs4, то `a[href^=#]:not(.nav-link)`, хотя это не только табы исключит, ну и другие навигационные списки бутстрапа

Comment: но к табам можете дописать классы свои таким же образом.

Comment: @teran через запятую?

Comment: @AndriiSoldatenko дополнил ответ примером